# ORMLite Save does not update model with the autoincrement identity

Tags: c#, mysql, servicestack, auto-increment, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using servicestack, ormlite, and mysql and Have linked table that are created within a transaction. Using the connection Save method, it should (according to documentation) update the model with the identity value. But it does not.

```
public bool SaveWithCredentials<T>(T model)
    {
        SetDefaultValues(false, model);
        var ret = Db.Save(model);
        return ret;
    }
```

(EDITED WITH MODEL)
The model:

```
 [Alias("orderEvent")]
public class OrderEvent
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [Alias("Identity")]
    public long Identity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(DbConstraints.STRING_36, DbConstraints.STRING_36)]
    [Alias("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(DbConstraints.STRING_36, DbConstraints.STRING_36)]
    [Alias("orderId")]
    public string OrderId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Alias("meaning")]
    public int Meaning { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Alias("subMeaning")]
    public int SubMeaning { get; set; }

    [Alias("quantity")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Alias("type")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [StringLength(DbConstraints.STRING_36, DbConstraints.STRING_36)]
    [Alias("servicesaleId")]
    public string ServiceSaleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(DbConstraints.STRING_36, DbConstraints.STRING_36)]
    [Alias("servicecenterId")]
    public string ServiceCenterId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(DbConstraints.STRING_36, DbConstraints.STRING_36)]
    [Alias("projectId")]
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }


    [Alias("ecoDate")]
    public DateTime EcoDate { get; set; }

    [Alias("createdDate")]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(DbConstraints.STRING_50)]
    [Alias("createdByName")]
    public string CreatedByName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(DbConstraints.STRING_36, DbConstraints.STRING_36)]
    [Alias("createdbyuserId")]
    public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(DbConstraints.STRING_2000)]
    [Alias("generalDescription")]
    public string GeneralDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(DbConstraints.STRING_50)]
    [Alias("sysecoactionId")]
    public string SysEcoActionId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Alias("sysOrderSerie")]
    public string SysOrderSerie { get; set; }

    [Alias("orderNbr")]
    public int? OrderNbr { get; set; }

    [Alias("itemNbr")]
    public int? ItemNbr { get; set; }
}
```

The IDBConnection.Save should update the field with the autoincrement identity in the model so that I can set the foreign key in the linked table, but it does not.

Does anyone have any idea? I cannot do the insert method, since it would have me doing major rewrite - which sort of negates the purpose of the Save method!

**UPDATE**
Tried the model in a test method with insert method and I get the identity returned then.

```
public long InsertForIdWithCredentials<T>(T model)
    {
        SetDefaultValues(false, model);
        var ret = Db.Insert(model, selectIdentity: true);
        return ret;
    }
```

the above code have no problem with returning identity even if it is generic.

/Erik

Comment: Can you update your question to include the definition of the "model" class with it's properties?

Comment: Updated with the model

Comment: This does work in OrmLite, can you try using the Save() API directly i.e. without going through a generic type as it's not clear from your usage what the generic T is and it needs to be the concrete type in order for OrmLite to access the metadata attributes for the Type.

Comment: I have a centralized utiltiy namepsace that handles all changes of every type of event in a financial system, but have had no need to use identity until now. Insert method works with generic type, so why shouldn't the Save method.

Since I cannot be sure when the event are handled if they exist in the database before, I would prefer not do additional roundtrips to the database to find out.

Comment: Like I said it needs the concrete Type, can you update the code with a standalone failing example we can run to see the issue? It's not possible to repro the issue from the description.

Comment: Okej, you say it needs the concrete type - that means I will have to rewrite. I've updated with the code for insert that works with generic.

It is only the save method that can't handle generics, since the insert can. Is this correct?